# SQL: Issue with WHERE on existing query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, where-clause

The query below is pulling the records with the max exdt/seq fields for each sku. The issue is instead of only picking up item 5343553 from the WHERE statement, it's pulling all items that 5343553's date/seqn is equal too. So in this case it's picking up 100+ records of different items that are equal to 5343553's max date of 7/1, seq 2.

```
SELECT *  
FROM 
    (SELECT   
         item, cpp, exdt, seq, tv_1 + tf_1 AS tt_1
     FROM         
         dbo.sample123) t 
PIVOT 
    (SUM(tt_1) FOR cpp IN ([M], [LL], [OH] AS pvtc

WHERE     
    (exdt = (SELECT MAX(exdt) AS exdtmax
             FROM dbo.sample123 AS b
             WHERE (LTRIM(item) IN ('5343553'))) 
    AND (seq = (SELECT MAX(seq) AS seqmax
                FROM dbo.sample123 AS b
                WHERE (LTRIM(item) IN ('5343553')))))
```

So I thought simple enough, I'll just remove the WHERE and it should give me all the skus with their max dates/seq. The below instead returns blank with no data?

```
SELECT *  
FROM 
    (SELECT   
         item, cpp, exdt, seq, tv_1 + tf_1 AS tt_1
     FROM dbo.sample123) t 
PIVOT 
    (SUM(tt_1) FOR cpp IN ([M], [LL], [OH] AS pvtc

WHERE     
    (exdt = (SELECT MAX(exdt) AS exdtmax
             FROM dbo.sample123 AS b))
    AND (seq = (SELECT MAX(seq) AS seqmax
                FROM dbo.sample123 AS b))
```

I'm not sure what I'm missing. Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks.

Comment: Properly formatted SQL is so much easier to read, and to write.

Comment: Microsoft SQL SMSS

Comment: Please provide a [mre] with sample data and desired results in addition to your query.

Comment: Use the aliases in the subqueries: `MAX(b.exdt)`, `MAX(b.seq)`.

Comment: I tried that - still didn't work.

Comment: by removing the where you getting the max field value for all records in the table.  first, write a query returning the data you want as a cte  or temp table then pivot data from the cte.  Break the task into steps that can be verified.

Comment: Side point: `MAX` as a window aggregate is probably more efficient

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding the question correctly and the issue with your first query is that it is not "only picking up item 5343553" then I suggest

```
WITH mycte AS
(
 SELECT *
 FROM dbo.sample123
 WHERE LTRIM(item) IN ('5343553')
)
SELECT *  
FROM 
    (SELECT   
         item, cpp, exdt, seq, tv_1 + tf_1 AS tt_1
     FROM         
         mycte) t 
PIVOT 
    (SUM(tt_1) FOR cpp IN ([M], [LL], [OH] AS pvtc 
WHERE     
    (exdt = (SELECT MAX(exdt) AS exdtmax
             FROM mycte) 
    AND (seq = (SELECT MAX(seq) AS seqmax
                FROM mycte))
```

The makes all of your subqueries apply that condition. (You could put the condition in all the subqueries, but the CTE means you only need to write it once.)

Based on comments below, I suspect what you actually want is something like the following, which returns all of the data, but only the rows where the maximums match for that item. Note that I used `LTRIM(t2.item)=LTRIM(t.item)` (instead of just `t2.item=t.item`) to be consistent with how you're doing it in the `WHERE` condition.

```
SELECT *  
FROM 
    (SELECT   
         item, cpp, exdt, seq, tv_1 + tf_1 AS tt_1
     FROM         
         dbo.sample123) t 
PIVOT 
    (SUM(tt_1) FOR cpp IN ([M], [LL], [OH] AS pvtc 
WHERE     
    exdt = (SELECT MAX(exdt) AS exdtmax
             FROM dbo.sample123 t2
             WHERE LTRIM(pvtc.item)=LTRIM(t.item)) 
    AND seq = (SELECT MAX(seq) AS seqmax
                FROM dbo.sample123 t2
                WHERE LTRIM(pvtc.item)=LTRIM(t.item))
```

And one more example that is probably cleaner:

```
SELECT *  
FROM 
    (SELECT   
         item, cpp, exdt, seq, tv_1 + tf_1 AS tt_1
     FROM         
         dbo.sample123 t
     WHERE
         exdt = (SELECT MAX(exdt) AS exdtmax
             FROM dbo.sample123 t2
             WHERE LTRIM(t2.item)=LTRIM(t.item)) 
         AND seq = (SELECT MAX(seq) AS seqmax
                FROM dbo.sample123 t2
                WHERE LTRIM(t2.item)=LTRIM(t.item))) t 
PIVOT 
    (SUM(tt_1) FOR cpp IN ([M], [LL], [OH] AS pvtc
```

Comment: That worked perfectly. My only issue is if I remove the WHERE LTRIM(item) in ('5343553') condition in the mycte section you added I would expect it to pull all skus then. Instead it's pulling blank with no data.

Comment: I assume that is correct... likely no lines match the maximum exdt and the maximum seq. (e.g. if the maximum exdt is 2099-01-01 from item2 and the maximum seq is 100 from item3, it is possible no rows match both).  It would be useful if you posted some actual data and what result you expect, but I will edit my response with a guess at what you are trying to do.

Comment: That worked, thanks. I had to adjust the t.item to pvtc.item in the WHERE, basically referencing the pivot. I was getting a could not be bound error with the t. I think that was part of my confusion as this is my first PIVOT function. Thanks.

Comment: Ah, right, my mistake. I will fix example. Likely moving the conditions into the subquery would make this mistake less likely.